# Kafka Streams API: KStream to KTable 1

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a cluster kafka with 3 brokers and  I have 300 topics.

I want to start processing using API kafka streams on each topic independently with others and write the results  of each input topic to specific topic

```
inputtopic1 to outputtopic1 
inputtopic2  to outputtopic2
inputtopic3 to outputtopic3
inputtopic4 to outputtopic4
```

etc

Any ideas ?

Comment: http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide.html#writing-streams-back-to-kafka    this ?

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide.html#writing-streams-back-to-kafka

**To() -> Terminal operation. Write the records to a Kafka topic. (KStream details, KTable details)**

When to provide serdes explicitly:

If you do not specify serdes explicitly, the default serdes from the configuration are used.
You must specificy serdes explicitly if the key and/or value types of the KStream or KTable do not match the configured default serdes.
See Data types and serialization for information about configuring default serdes, available serdes, and implementing your own custom serdes.
Several variants of to exist to e.g. specify a custom StreamPartitioner that gives you control over how output records are distributed across the partitions of the output topic.

Comment: Thanks , it is very helpful , i have another question please , i want to write these processed data to C*  using the spark cassandra connector this is my code